# React Using useState/Hooks In HOC Causes Error "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is it not allowed to use hooks inside of a Higher Order Component? When I try to do it with this simple pattern I'm getting the error `Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

```jsx
// App.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const WithState = (Component) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useState(0);
  return () => <Component state={state} dispatch={dispatch} />;
}

const Counter = ({ state }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', margin: '0 auto'}}>
      {state}
    </div>
  )
}

const CounterWithState = WithState(Counter);

const App = () => {
  return <CounterWithState />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe you should use the hooks inside the HOC:

```
const WithState = (Component) => {
  const WithStateComponent = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useState(0);
    return <Component state={state} dispatch={dispatch} />;
  }
  return WithStateComponent;
}
```

Comment: Hooks should be called inside a component, not higher-order component. To keep it straight, what you called `WithState` may called `WithStateHOC` because it's higher-order component, i.e. a function that returns a component. And what you called `WithStateHOC` may be called `WithStateComponent`. The code is correct but terminology is confusing.

Comment: Thanks this solves it. I noticed that without the WithStateComponent variable you get an `<Unknown>` element in the React debugger so this helps with clarity as well.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Rafael Souza's answer, you can make it even cleaner with:

```
const WithState = (Component) => {
  return () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useState(0);
    return <Component state={state} dispatch={dispatch} />
  }
}
```

Comment: That cause "Hooks cannot be used inside callbacks"